# New unwanted desktop icons after 20.04 upgrade

Tags: desktop-icons

successfully upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04.

Now got loads of folder icons on the desktop, including hidden folders (.bash_logout, .Xauthority, .gnome2, to name but a few). I only need links to 'Documents', 'Pictures' and 'Rubbish Bin'.

How do I remove the other 30-odd without breaking anything?

Cheers

JM

Comment: `mv .config/user-dirs.dirs .config/user-dirs.dirs.bak`  then `xdg-user-dirs-update`

Comment: And what would that do?

Comment: It would do what you asked to do.

Comment: the 1.  renames the file, so it is not lost after all. the 2. command recreates .config/user-dirs.dirs anew

Comment: So it would remove the unwanted folder icons,  but leave 'Documents', 'Rubbish Bin' etc.?  Honestly?

Comment: Big thank you to Mr/Ms 'Nobody';  the solution worked, and I now know how to add folders to the desktop by editing the ./config/user-dirs.dirs text file. And thank you for providing the extra information:  I know about copying/mv-ing files, but the xdg command is new to me. Thanks again!